# How do I select rows where a column value starts with a certain string?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How do I select rows where a column value starts with a certain string ?

For example, I'd like to select the rows whose 'name' column starts with "Mr.".

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can do

```
select * from mytable where name like "Mr.%"
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html